# Calculate the avarage amount of items posted per day/month/year using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate the average amount of social media posts posted per day/month/year

given data with this structure:

```py
[{'created_utc': 1669804989}, {'created_utc': 1669804782}, {'created_utc': 1669804772}] # etc...
```

(Its thousands of entries in length)

I came up with the following code:

```py
import datetime

def unix_to_utc(unix_time: int):
    utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time)

    return datetime.date(
        utc.year, utc.month, utc.day
    )

def avarege_number(numbers: list) -> float:
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)


def grop_by_day(posts: list) -> list: 
    items = []

    for post in posts:
        items.append(
            unix_to_utc(post['created_utc'])
        )

    grouped = []

    for date in items:
        appended = False

        for group in grouped:
            if group[0] != date:
                continue

            group.append(date)

            appended = True

        if not appended:
            grouped.append(
                [date]
            )

    return grouped

def post_per(posts: list):
    grouped = grop_by_day(post)

    var_name = []

    for i in grouped:
        var_name.append(
            len(i)
        )

    return avarege_number(
        var_name
    )
```

calling the code:

```
data = [{'created_utc': 1669804989}, {'created_utc': 1669804782}, {'created_utc': 1669804772}]

result = post_per(data)
```

There are a lot of problems with the code but i cant think of a better solution.

The main one is that it dose not account for days with no posts.
And i have no idea how to calculate per month/year

Comment: Please provide realistic unix time values, arbitrary numbers don't allow for testing.  How are you calling these functions?  Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group the dates by Day/Month/Year:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'created_utc': 1669804989}, {'created_utc': 1669804782}, {'created_utc': 1669894772},
        {'created_utc': 1669904989}, {'created_utc': 1669904782}, {'created_utc': 1669904772},
        {'created_utc': 1679804989}, {'created_utc': 1679804782}, {'created_utc': 1679804772}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['created_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_utc'], unit='s')
df['count'] = 0

print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_utc', freq='D')).count())
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_utc', freq='MS')).count())
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_utc', freq='YS')).count())
```

Output:

```
             count # Day
created_utc       
2022-11-30       2
2022-12-01       4
2022-12-02       0
2022-12-03       0
2022-12-04       0
...            ...
2023-03-22       0
2023-03-23       0
2023-03-24       0
2023-03-25       0
2023-03-26       3

[117 rows x 1 columns]

             count # Month
created_utc       
2022-11-01       2
2022-12-01       4
2023-01-01       0
2023-02-01       0
2023-03-01       3

             count # Year
created_utc       
2022-01-01       6
2023-01-01       3
```

You can then compute the average of these dataframes with `mean()`.